# Get GPS Coordinates : Android

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm new to Android development. As a class assignment another student and myself are making an android app that will utilize GPS coordinates.

Is there anywhere that would be a good place for me to start with GPS feature on Android, or that has a good example of how to use GPS? I don't want anything deep, literally just how to retrieve and use current GPS coordinates. I'd like to start simple and build up from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well mostly GPS coordinates are used along with Google Maps. So, as a starter what you can do is just get your own coordinates and put a marker on your location on the map.
This [article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) and [this one](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) describes everything about using google maps with android.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in one of the other answers, Vogella's article [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#locationapi) is very good for learning the basics of using GPS on Android.

The Android Dev guides are also particularly good for this area - obviously there are issues with battery drain associated with using location listeners. More in-depth information on what you can do to combat those issues are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html), as when you get to grips with how to use GPS, you'll want to use it efficiently!

HTH

Answer (score 7):

http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/geting-current-location-in-android-application-using-gps/

this will be a good start. it explains how to get GPS coordinates as text format. Without dealing with google maps or anything complex.